# How do you specify to display a diamond in a NSMenuItem (minimized window indicator)?

Tags: java, objective-c, cocoa, macos, java-native-interface

I'm creating a JNI to display an application wide menu bar instead of the JFrame specific one. This allows me to keep a menubar displayed even when no JFrames are present. I've hit a small snag, in my window menu I can't figure out how to display a diamond for the windows that are minimized. As far as I can tell in the standard API there's only three states available On, Off, and Mixed where mixed is a dash. Is there a way to show the minimized diamond using standard API? Or am I going to have to create a diamond image and use that?

Comment: Are you using NSMenu, or some Java menu API?

Comment: NSMenu. I guess most of the java stuff is irrelevant, I just wanted to make it clear I'm not able to use cocoa's built in handling of the window menu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AppKit isn't using a public API to get this image. It's using _NSGetThemeImage which pulls an image out of the old HIToolbox Appearance Manager theme resources and converts it an NSImage. I wan't able to find an equivalent public API.

If you want to mimic how AppKit does it, use:

```
NSImage* _NSGetThemeImage(int num);

[menuitem setState:NSOnState];
[menuitem setOnStateImage:_NSGetThemeImage(155)];
```

Better yet, use this code to grab the NSImage, save it to a TIFF file, and then include that TIFF in your program. That way you avoid using private APIs in the shipping code. I doubt Apple would complain that you're stealing their diamond. ;)

Comment: Ugh, that sucks. Oh well, at least there's a way to do it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The documentation for `setOnStateImage:` says "Changing state images is currently unsupported in Mac OS X."  Does that mean your solution shouldn't work?

Comment: Well, I tried it before posting the answer and so yes it works.